# Fit Image inside a photo frame using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to add the uploaded image to the white area inside the frame. How to do that please help. Is there any library or plugin for that.

[image]

Comment: With php you can not do that. Do it with CSS and an absolute div (position absolute and overflow hidden) which contains the image.

Comment: I need to give set top left positions static then. I am having multiple templates like this, want something like this where it auto detects that white rectangle part and fits in the image.

Comment: You need to have the coordinates of the rectangle then you can place your image inside those coordinates.

Comment: How to get coordinates, is there any script for that?

Comment: If you do not want to write down the fixed coordinates of each image, you have to get them e.g. over an AI like the google vision object detection, Tensorflow-js or pixfinder (not realy an AI)

Comment: 1: you can do this with PHP using GD  or Imagemagick. 2: your question is too broad as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer{
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZfgh.jpg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.inner{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: 116px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 110px;
  height: 138px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  Hello
  </div>
</div>
```